# What game used how much your character cared as a resource?

Tags: product-identification

I found a game system once that I'm trying to find again. A few minutes of Googling hasn't availed me any success. The main features I remember are:

- It was a modern-day Lovecraftian setting.
- The characters were potential cultists, who Cthulu wanted, but who weren't cultists yet.
- The conflict resolution mechanic involved how much that character cares about otherworldly things; by caring more, they succeeded more often, but if they care too much, they become a cultist.
- Player table talk was audible to the characters in the game. This is a specific game rule that was in the book, and not just the way the game was played at a particular table.
- There we're creatures called Apartment Liches that cared so little that they stopped needing food or water, and didn't age.
- The game had a tongue-in-cheek humourous style to the writing.
- Every adventure started with a Headline, something interesting that the characters see in the newspaper.
- It may have been called Apathy.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Apathy: The Calling

Is... [this](http://www.1km1kt.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/apathy_the_calling_final.pdf) your card? A 2008 Game Chef entry found on 1km1kt.net, featuring Cthulhu, cultists, and a tongue in cheek humorous style.

**The conflict resolution mechanic involved how much that character cares about otherworldly things; by caring more, they succeeded more often, but if they care too much, they become a cultist.**

From section [1.3.3.4] Apathy Bidding

> If someone is unsatisfied with the result of either a player or gm conflict, they have a option. A Player or GM may bid apathy to overturn a loss.

**Player table talk was audible to the characters in the game.**

From section [1.3.2] Character Sheet (all typos dutifully and faithfully preserved):

> Kewl Powers from Ryleh:  This is the list of powerz that you have. Every character has I can hear Cthulhu telling me to do evil stuff, lol. 
>   that's your first power. you know all that player table jawing that goes on like shoot him in the face. Roflcopters and lollerskates abound in your head. You can hear the player chat, so feel free to act on it. The voices come directly from cthlolhu however so expect your mileage to vary.

**Every adventure started with a Headline, something interesting that the characters see in the newspaper.**

From section [1.3.5] Headlines

> Headlines are a way of advertising what the  PC's are doing, how well they are doing it, and where the person making the headline would like the game to go.

Comment: [Links to external resources are encouraged](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. The Stack wants answers which connect all the dots, without leaving anything as an exercise for the reader, so please explain how this solution fits the question describes.

Comment: @BESW, I added the source and a brief description of the content. What else would you suggest?

Comment: The querent provided a great list of qualities; a really top-notch answer would compare each of those qualities to the game being suggested and talk about how they either match up or don't, with a conclusion about the likelihood of the game being the right one based on matching criteria.